# Locale.UK and country code

Tags: java, internationalization, iso

According to the [ISO 2 character codes](http://www.spoonfork.org/isocodes.html) **uk = United Kingdom**. But `Locale.UK.getCountry()` is returning **GB**. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/locale/),

> The getCountry() method returns the ISO 3166 two-letter abbreviation for the locale's region or country member.

The [ISO 3166 two-letter abbreviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) for the UK is indeed GB. `uk` is not part of the standard, but more of a historical accident:

> The use of .uk rather than .gb for the top-level domain is due to its pre-existing use in the (now obsolete) JANET Name Registration Scheme in which the order of address components were reversed. .uk was made available in DNS to simplify the translation to and from these addresses. There were plans for eventual transition to .gb to accord with correct usage, but this never occurred; the use of .uk is now entrenched, and it is impossible to register a .gb domain.

Depending on your target use, you may need to replace .gb with .uk.

Answer (score 1):

`uk` is there for compatibility reasons (a mistake in the past).

The correct id is `gb`.

The only place where `gb` remains standard is the domain names, but this is outside the scope of this question.

To minimize potential issues you could remap `uk` to `gb`.

Comment: Is there a standard alias api?

Comment: It is not an alias in any official way. You can have it as a compatibility mapping if you deal with some non-standard system.